# How do you convert ASCII string to UTF 8 string with emoji in Ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding

```
text = "\x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x01\xFF\xFEM\x00y\x00 \x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00C\x00H\x00A\x00P\x00T\x00E\x00R\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00 \x00E\x00E\x00E\x00=\xD8\x0E\xDEE\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00"

text = text.encode('UTF-8', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)
=> "\u0000\u0000\u0000=\u0000\u0000\u0001��M\u0000y\u0000 \u0000*\u0000*\u0000*\u0000*\u0000C\u0000H\u0000A\u0000P\u0000T\u0000E\u0000R\u0000*\u0000*\u0000*\u0000*\u0000*\u0000 \u0000E\u0000E\u0000E\u0000=�\u000E�E\u0000E\u0000E\u0000E\u0000"

puts "#{text}"
=��My ****CHAPTER***** EEE=��EEEE
```

The original string looks like this "My ****CHAPTER***** EEEEEEE"

Comment: In the code sample above, your original string is not `""My ****CHAPTER***** EEEEEEE"`, it's `"chp0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0F\xA0\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFFTIT2\x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x01\xFF\xFEM\x00y\x00 \x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00C\x00H\x00A\x00P\x00T\x00E\x00R\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00 \x00E\x00E\x00E\x00=\xD8\x0E\xDEE\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00WXXX\x00\x00\x00&\x00\x00\x00chapter url\x00http://www.aol.com/123123"`. How did you end up with that string to start with? How do you know the "correct" version is what's written below?

Comment: For example, how do you know that you need to `text.split('TIT2')[1].split('WXXX')[0]`? Such a transformation cannot possibly be needed if you all you're doing is converting a string from one encoding to another.

Comment: The string contains a bunch of data. I am trying to strip out the title with the emoji in it. I know what to look for (TIT2 and WXXX) to split the string to only return the text of the title. In other words the following string should be the title \x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x01\xFF\xFEM\x00y\x00 \x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00C\x00H\x00A\x00P\x00T\x00E\x00R\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00 \x00E\x00E\x00E\x00=\xD8\x0E\xDEE\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00

Comment: @tom I edited the question by simplifying the code

Comment: I do not know 100% that the original string and my text string are the same. That would be my problem if that is the case - but i just dont know enough about string encoding and binary to determine that.

Comment: The string you claim is an ASCII string is most definitely not an ASCII string, since it contains bytes that are not encodings of a valid ASCII character. ASCII only has 128 characters which are encoded as 0x00–0x7F, but your string contains for example the bytes 0xFE and 0xFF. In order for us to help you, you need to first tell us what encoding that string is in, because it is definitely not ASCII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original string contains 7 bytes of garbage, the [`BOM`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), and then your target string in `UTF_16LE`.

```
puts text[9..-1].force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16LE).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
#⇒ My ****CHAPTER***** EEEEEEE
```

---

Most likely in all the cases your *string* starts with `BOM`. To detect it you might use:

```
_, idx =
  text.chars.each_cons(2).with_index.detect do |(c1, c2), _|
    c1 == "\xFF" && c2 == "\xFE"
  end
```

and then:

```
puts text[idx+2..-1].force_encoding(Encoding::UTF_16LE).encode(Encoding::UTF_8)
#⇒ My ****CHAPTER***** EEEEEEE
```

Comment: Thanks! I will accept this as the answer. For some reason when I use one program to write that data it appears differently than when I write it and read it. IDK if you understand this but this is essentially what the code is doing to write this data     chaps = []
          title = "My ****CHAPTER***** EEEEEEE"
          title_tag = [title.encode("utf-16")].pack("a*");
          chap << "TIT2"
          chap << [title_tag.size+1].pack("N")
          chap << "\x00\x00\x01"
         chap << title_tag

Comment: I see its because the encoding is different utf-16 versus your utf-16le